# How to create a test run/plan for a C++ Program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, oop

Hi I have a c++ class called `Date`. The codes are below. How to create a test run for the class? Am very much new to C++. I have searched a lot but couldn't able find any fruitful/useful websites for that. Please someone can help? Thanks in advance.

`date.h`

```
#ifndef H_date
#define H_date 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class Date{
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream & os, const Date &);
    friend istream &operator >> (istream & is, Date &);

public:
    Date();
    Date(int day, int month, int year);
    void setday(int day);
    void setmonth(int month);
    void setyear(int year);
    void setDate(int day, int month, int year);
    int getday() const;
    int getmonth() const;
    int getyear() const;
    void print() const;
protected:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year; 
};
#endif
```

`date.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;
Date::Date()
{
    day = 0;
    month = 0;
    year = 0;
}
Date::Date(int newDay, int newMonth, int newYear)
{
    day = newDay;
    month = newMonth;
    year = newYear;
}
void Date::setday(int newDay)
{
    day =newDay;
}
void Date::setmonth(int newMonth)
{
    month = newMonth;
}
void Date::setyear(int newYear)
{
    year = newYear;
}

void Date::setDate(int newDay, int newMonth, int newYear)
{
    day =newDay;
    month = newMonth;
    year = newYear;
}
int Date::getday()const
{
    return day;

}
int Date::getmonth()const
{
    return month;

}
int Date::getyear()const
{
    return year;

}

void Date::print()const
{
    cout << day << ":" << month<< ":" << year <<endl;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream& osObject, const Date& date1)
{
    osObject << date1.day
        << ":" <<date1.month
        << ":" << date1.year;
    return osObject;

}
istream& operator>> (istream& isObject, Date& date1)
{
    isObject>>date1.day>>date1.month>>date1.year;
    return isObject;

}
```

Comment: If you call `setday` with a specific value, does `getday` return the correct value? It's really that simple to test a class: Use the setter functions to set a specific value (data in your case) and check that the getter functions returns the correct values. For the input/output functions, use a `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: "create a test run" means "unit test" ?

Comment: You cannot imagine how little I want to write test specs for other people for free.

Comment: Yes Nayana.. Unit Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *unit tests*, you would typically use a unit-test framework such as [CppUnit](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/cppunit_cookbook.html):

- For each class, you create a series of test;
- For each method to be tested, you develop a dedicated test;
- Each test verifies some assertions using functions or macros such as [CPPUNIT_ASSERT](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/group___assertions.html), CPPUNIT_FAIL, CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW;
- It's often useful to make the tester class `friend` to the tested class.

Here is an example for testing your constructors:

```
void DateUnitTest::ConstructorTests
{
    // Test default-ctor
    { 
        Date date;
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT ( date.day   == 0 );
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT ( date.month == 0 );
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT ( date.year  == 0 );
    }

    // Test ctor with args
    { 
        Date date(31,12,2015);
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT ( date.day   == 31 );
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT ( date.month == 12 );
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT ( date.year  == 2015 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. How to run this? I already have a main program. Do I need to create a different project for this?

Comment: @Blacky Yes, this is done is a separate project / a dedicated unit-test program. This way, your build-chain is pretty simple: (1) build unit-test program (2) run unit-test program (3) check for no errors. If those 3 steps are ok and your test-plan is exhaustive enough you know everything is ok at unit-level. You may need to add some further testings (integration, performance and/or stress), but that's the 1st step :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel :)